# ODE of form $\dot{f} = f^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a quick question of ODE:

$\dot{f}(t) = f^2(t) $

$f(0) = 1$
(I made the initial condition up)

I try to guess the solution to this ODE but it’s hard to image some function whose derivative at any point is exactly the squared value at the point. Can anyone give some hints please?

Comment: Try $\dfrac{df}{f^2}=dt,$ and integrate.

Comment: Hint: what is the derivative of $1/f(x)$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Separation of variables leads to

$$\int \frac{\mathrm d f}{f^2} = \int \mathrm d t.$$

Integration gives us

$$- \frac{1}{f} = t + c$$

with a real $c$. From the initial condition one gets $ c = -1$, so the solution of the IVP is

$$f(t) = - \frac{1}{t -1}.$$

Comment: Thx a lot! How about f’=f^2+c (constant)?  Does it make it inseparable?

Comment: @JulyJ No, you still can separate to $\frac{\mathrm df}{f^2 + c} = \mathrm dt$.

Comment: Oh yeah, it was a dumb question. Thank you!